# How to recall a string in shell script

Tags: shell

I made a script like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
a=`ls ../wrfprd/wrfout_d0${i}* | cut -c22-25`
b=`ls ../wrfprd/wrfout_d0${i}* | cut -c27-28`
c=`ls ../wrfprd/wrfout_d0${i}* | cut -c30-31`
d=`ls ../wrfprd/wrfout_d0${i}* | cut -c33-34`

f=$a$b$c$d
echo $f

sed "s/.* startdate=.*/export startdate=${f}/g" ./post_process > post_process2
```

echo command works and gives `2008042118` that is what I want but in file post_process2 is like this `export startdate=` and can not recall variable f. I want to produce a line like `export startdate=2008042118`

Comment: try this: export startdate=$f/g

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: `ls` is not a tool for programmatic use. You shouldn't use it in scripts unless generating content for humans to read (not for those scripts to interact with); see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, code-generation is, in general, error-prone. What are you **really** trying to accomplish? There are better ways to write a value to disk for other scripts to use.

Comment: Could you provide an example value for the filename you're trying to extract components of? This would also give us an opportunity to provide a better way to extract the components you want than `cut`. (Parameter expansions are the preferred way to generate fixed-offset components).

Comment: Anyhow, it's very doubtful that there's actually a "recall" problem. More likely your `sed` expression just isn't doing what you expect, but we couldn't say anything useful about why without seeing what it actually is. Running your code with `set -x`, or invoking the shell as `bash -x yourscript`, will be helpful there.

Comment: If you want a better answer, please revise your question per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- that is, it should include a **minimal, complete, verifiable** example; "verifiable" means we should be able to run your code and get the same bug, which right now we can't do because it requires a `wrfprd` directory and a `post_process` template, but doesn't create either.

Comment: dear Charles filename is wrfout_d01_2008-04-21_18:00:00 and I want to extract 2008042118 and whrite it in file post_process3. thanks

Answer (score 2):

First -- don't use `ls` here -- it's both expensive in terms of performance (compared to globbing, which is performed internal to the shell without starting any external programs), and doesn't guarantee useful output for the full range of possible filenames, [making its use in this context inherently bug-prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A better way to retrieve pieces from a filename, assuming a ksh-derived shell such as bash or zsh, would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is an array, but we're only going to use the first element
file=( "../wrfprd/wrfout_d0${i}"* )
[[ -e $file ]] ||  { echo "No file found" >&2; exit 1; }
f=${file:22:4}${file:27:2}${file:30:2}${file:33:2}
```

Second, don't use `sed` to modify code -- doing so requires that your runtime user have permission to modify its own code, and moreover invites injection vulnerabilities. Just write your content out to a data file:

```
printf '%s\n' "$f" >startdate.txt
```

...and, in your second script, to read in the value from that file:

```
# if the shebang is #!/bin/bash
startdate=$(<startdate.txt)

# if the shebang is #!/bin/sh
startdate=$(cat startdate.txt)
```